# Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, material-components-android

This is my app theme:
`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">`

I got an inflate error caused by a not using a desired theme. In the `Manifest` I didn't overwrite the theme for the activity that I got this error, so the AppTheme definded in `styles.xml` is used.

Error:

```
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #122: Binary XML file line #122: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #122: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
      ...
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:240)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkMaterialTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:215)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:143)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainTintedStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:116)
```

And this is my xml:

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/inputFirstName"
                        style="@style/EditText.OutlinedBox"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/colorBrand"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
```

and the EditText style:

```
 <style name="EditText.OutlinedBox" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
        <item name="android:minHeight">56dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/nunito_regular</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorTextSecondary</item>
        <item name="hintTextColor">@color/colorBrand</item>
        <item name="hintEnabled">true</item>
    </style>
```

target sdk of the app is 29 and I use `material_design_components_version = '1.1.0-alpha08'`

EDIT:

from `app/gradle`

```
    implementation(
        "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appcompat_version",
        "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$constraintlayout_version",
        "com.google.android.material:material:$material_design_components_version"
)
```

Manifest:

```
<application
    android:name=".application.BaseApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

Theme:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/nunito_regular</item>
    <item name="android:lineSpacingExtra">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:includeFontPadding">false</item>
    <item name="navigationIcon">@drawable/ic_back_dark</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/AppBottomSheetDialogTheme</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Add android:theme="Theme.MaterialComponents"  to the layout.

Comment: not working, crash with the same message

Comment: Pls show us how your design reference looks like in gradle. It very much looks like you're mixing appcompat and androidx. Pls also add look of your manifest -  app theme in particular.

Comment: @ror i have added the details

Comment: Hm can it be that your AppTheme has different representations for different sdk versions, and is not properly inherited for version you are testing against? @ghita

Comment: I dont understandm what you are reffering to @ror

Comment: I will try to rephrase: there is one impl of AppTheme under res/values/styles.xml, another under res/values-v23/styles/xml etc.

Comment: @ror got it now. not my case, I have only one AppTheme defined

Comment: have you find a solution for that issue? I have encountered this problem and couldn't find any solution yet @ghita

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try in parent layout apply this style:

**android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar"**

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
       
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
```

This is an example,for complete using, put in your app style the parent,Exemple:

```
<style name="MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
```

Comment: Setting a theme in the Layout can be a useful debugging tool.  However, a typical application would set an application-wide theme in AndroidManifest.xml.  This theme is often defined in `values/themes.xml` and should have a parent of `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar` (or similar).

Answer (score 7):

I implemented this:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

Then I changed the style from:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

To:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 launchFragmentInContainer<LoginFragment>(themeResId =R.style.AppTheme)
```

add theme in constructor!!

Comment: This is the only thing that I had to do. Worked like a charm, thank you!

Comment: @renatoarg you are welcome, glad to hear that it helped to someone.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution.Life Saver for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the material version.
Try changing your version alpha06 and it should fix it:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06'
```

Comment: no, the problem was that textinput was inside a dialog, and the context that i used for dialog was the activity context and not the fragment context, that opent the dialog

Comment: This seems to work fine for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

check your theme inheritance, in my case in light theme I inherited with material component and in the dark theme from material3